# Using RwLock.read() on a mutable struct

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, rwlock

I'm trying to use a RwLock around a mutable struct, but I can't make it compile and I'm not sure why.

Here's a minimum code sample:

```rust
use std::sync::RwLock;
use lru::LruCache;

fn main() {
        let mut cache: LruCache<String,String> = LruCache::new(100);
        cache.put("test".to_string(), "test_value".to_string());
        let lock_cache = RwLock::new(cache);
        let rc = lock_cache.read();
        let res = rc.unwrap().get("test");
        assert_eq!(res.unwrap().as_str(), "test_value");
}
```

where `LruCache` comes from an external Rust crate (but I don't think it has a specific role in the issue).
The compiler complains with this message:

```rust
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in a dereference of `RwLockReadGuard<'_, LruCache<String, String>>` as mutable
   --> tests/cache_test.rs:295:15
    |
295 |     let res = rc.unwrap().get("test");
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
    |
    = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `RwLockReadGuard<'_, LruCache<String, String>>`
```

I checked the docs for `RwLock` and while `RwLockWriteGuard` does implement `DerefMut`, `RwLockReadGuard` does not.

I'm quite new to Rust so I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong. Is there a way I can workaround the `DerefMut` is required but not implemented, compiler error?

**EDIT** I changed the code so that is easily executable from a main file.

Comment: Where does `LruCache` come from?

Comment: Hi Andrea, welcome to [SO], could you kindly modify your code so it can be tested. Have a look at [ask] ;)

Comment: @justinas It comes from a crate called `lru`

Comment: The `.read()` method is for the *read* part of the `RwLock`, it provides read, a.k.a. immutable, access to the protected value. Perhaps you wanted [`.write()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html#method.write)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LruCache::get` requires `&mut self`, as per its signature ([docs](https://docs.rs/lru/0.7.0/lru/struct.LruCache.html#method.get)):

```rust
pub fn get<'a, Q>(&'a mut self, k: &Q) -> Option<&'a V>
```

This is because of the nature of LRU caches: in order to keep track which items were most recently used, the cache needs to modify (write) its state:

> <...> Moves the key to the head of the LRU list if it exists.

even though you're doing a "read" operation.

So, in your case, `RwLock` wins you nothing over `Mutex`, as you have to acquire a write lock anyway. The simplest options are either to use a `Mutex<LruCache<K, V>>` instead, or choose another way of caching.

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought about how LRUs work, you're absolutely right! I already have a working version of my project that uses `Mutex<LruCache<K,V>>` and was experimenting with `RwLock`, so I'll stick with that.